# .htaccess file exact match and not exact match

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I just moved to a WordPress site. I used to have a static site and a WordPress blog on a subdomain (`blog.example.com`). I'm using the code below, which is redirecting all of my blog posts to my new website perfectly fine. Is there any way to make an exception for the main blog page? To be specific, I need the code below to apply to all my posts, categories, etc. (which it already is), but I need my old blog home page (`blog.example.com`) to 301 redirect to my new blog homepage (`example.com/blog`). Just to be very clear, my posts, etc. are NOT using `blog` in the permalink.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

UPDATE: Thanks, Olaf! Got this working with your advice. Here is my final code for anyone else looking for an answer.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/blog [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Remember to escape dots in regex to match a literal dot and not any character. ie. `^blog\.example\.com$`. Or, use a lexicographical comparison. eg `=blog.example.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Put the most specific rules at the beginning. In your case, prepend the existing rule with the redirect for the main page

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/blog [R,L]
```

---

When everything works as it should, you may replace `R` with `R=301`. *Never* test with [`R=301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).